# How to identify contour which are not directly separated from each other?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, javacv

Please can some one explain how to identify square shape of contours which are not exactly separated each other. For example I need to identify the number of squares in below image and the x,y coordinates of their edges. I try to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093654/how-to-identify-square-or-rectangle-with-variable-lengths-and-width-by-using-jav) question but it didn't work for me.

[image]

So please can some one explain this using simple code example.

This is the image that I can generated can you please explain how to identify above squares in this image.

[image]

So please be kind enough to explain this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use fact, that red component of each square equals 255, and do the threshold. Here's what I've done:

1. Do a red color segmentation:
   [image]
2. Do dilatation (to remove holes):
   [image]
3. (Optional) Do a check if each contour is a square.

Code:

```
Mat src = imread("input.png"), red;
extractChannel(src, red, 2);

threshold(red, red, 254, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size( 2, 2 ), Point( 1, 1 ));
dilate(red, red, element);
```

Comment: Hay Thank you very much for your quick reply. Can you please tell me if those squares are having same color like other lines how could I extract those squares ? Please be kind enough to explain that.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean if whole the image have only black colored lines how could I identify those squares ?

Comment: Lines are not squares. What are you talking about?

Comment: I have updated the question by uploading sample image to it. In that kind of image how can I identify those squares ?

Comment: @NadLnk if you have accepted my answer, than your question is already answered. Ask a new question and I will help you.

Comment: @Astor I had ask it as separate question could you please give some sort of solution for that as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088176/identify-contours-in-a-image-which-are-having-same-color-using-opencv-or-javacv Thanks