# Filling edges using flood fill not working properly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, flood-fill

I am using openCV in python to detect cracks in concrete. I am able to use canny edge detection to detect cracks. Next, I need to fill the edges. I used floodfill operation of openCV but some of the gaps are filled whereas some are not filled. The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdKMb.jpg) on the left is the input image whereas that on the right is the floodfilled [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdKMb.jpg). I am guessing this is because my edges have breaks at points. How do i solve this ?
My code for floodfilling:

```
im_th1 = imginput
im_floodfill = im_th1.copy()
# Mask used to flood filling.
# Notice the size needs to be 2 pixels than the image.
h, w = im_th1.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h + 2, w + 2), np.uint8)

# Floodfill from point (0, 0)
cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (5, 5), 255);

# Invert floodfilled image
im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)

# Combine the two images to get the foreground.
im_out = im_th1 | im_floodfill_inv
cv2.imshow("Foreground", im_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to what i was looking for. Posting it here as it might come of use to others. After some research on the internet, it was just 2 lines of codes as suggested in this : [How to complete/close a contour in python opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009923/how-to-complete-close-a-contour-in-python-opencv/53533399#53533399)

The code that worked for me is :

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9, 9))
dilated = cv2.dilate(image, kernel)
eroded=cv2.erode(dilated,kernel)
```

The result is in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N56xa.jpg) attached that shows before and after results.

Answer (score 1):

I see this so often here on SO, everybody wants to use edge detection, and then fill in the area in between the edges.

Unless you use a method for edge detection that purposefully creates a closed contour, detected edges will likely not form a closed contour. And you cannot flood-fill a region unless you have a closed contour.

In most of these cases, some filtering and a simple threshold suffice. For example:

```
import PyDIP as dip
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

img = dip.Image(pp.imread('oJAo7.jpg')).TensorElement(1) # From OP's other question
img = img[4:698,6:]

lines = dip.Tophat(img, 10, polarity='black')
dip.SetBorder(lines, [0], [2])
lines = dip.PathOpening(lines, length=100, polarity='opening', mode={'robust'})
lines = dip.Threshold(lines, method='otsu')[0]
```

[image: output of script]

This result is obtained after a simple top-hat filter, which keeps only thin things, followed by a path opening, which keeps only long things. This combination removes large-scale shading, as well as the small bumps and things. After the filtering, a simple Otsu threshold yields a binary image that marks all pixels in the crack.

Notes:

- The input image is the one OP posted [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350136/distance-between-two-curves-after-edge-detection), and is the input to the images posted in this question.
- I'm using PyDIP, which you can [get on GitHub](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) and need to compile yourself. Hopefully soon we'll have a binary distribution. I'm an author.

Comment: I get the error : "module 'pydip' has no attribute 'Image'" when i use the above code. I tried to install the PyDIP library using PIP install PyDIP. Isn't this the correcct way ? Your output looks so promising but not working here !

Comment: @Eshant: No, you cannot install PyDIP through `pip`, we don't have a binary distribution yet, you need to compile from sources.