# Opencv plot black pixels on a image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I have a input image similar to

[image]

I am referring to:
 [How to fill the gaps in letters after Canny edge detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486910/how-to-fill-the-gaps-in-letters-after-canny-edge-detection)

I want to plot black pixels on this image. The proposed solution on the above url is first find all black pixels using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import numpy as np

image = pp.imread(r'/home/cris/tmp/Zuv3p.jpg')
bin = np.all(image<100, axis=2)
```

My question is dow do I plot this black pixels (data stored in bin ) on image while ignoring all other colour channels.

Comment: What do you mean by "plot the black pixels"? Do you want to show a histogram of the black pixels after you've extracted them?

Comment: No, I want to cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', image). Where image highlights only the language in the above image. I want to highlight the letters and remove the background from the image

Comment: The question you linked already does that.

Comment: The suggested solution in above link finds all pixels where all three channels are below a value of 100.  I want to plot the image with these newly defined values below 100

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the answer is stated that `np.all(image<100, axis=2)` is used to select pixels where R,G and B are all lower then 100, which is basically color separation. Personally, I like to use the HSV-colorspace for that.

Result:

[image]

Note: if you want to improve the green letters, it is best to create a separate mask for that, and tweak the hsv values for green.

Code:

```
    import numpy as np 
    import cv2
    # load image
    img = cv2.imread("img.jpg")

     # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of black color in HSV
    lower_val = np.array([0,0,0])
    upper_val = np.array([179,255,127])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only black colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

    # invert mask to get black symbols on white background
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

    # display image
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask_inv)
    cv2.imshow("Img", img)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I found this answer for a project I am working on. I am trying to do something similar. Although I do not want to extract grey, i only want BLACK. When I use this it is pulling a lot of the background from my image. I have been messing around with the upper_val numbers but cant get it right.  What would the Upper/lower vals have to be to only pull out TRUE black, and then I can try and work from there.

Comment: The upper_val numbers are [Hue, Saturation,Value]. as you can see in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:HSV_color_solid_cylinder_saturation_gray.png) image, you want all hue, all saturation, and threshold the Value. Lower = darker. You can test values on your image using [this script](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator)

Comment: If with true black you mean #000000, i would suggest using a [binary threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)