# How to close a contour with OpenCV when dilating isn't enough

Tags: python, opencv

I have been looking to close contour for shapes that are similar to circles or rounded objects.

I found a very interesting answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009923/how-to-complete-close-a-contour-in-python-opencv).

I thought my problem was solved until I tested with different images.

This is my mask from OpenCV canny AFTER dilating. As you can see, there is a big gap at the bottom.

[image]

If the shape was a circle, I could try to recreate the circle, but the thing is the shape could be different. I could look like a cucumber or a rugby balloon.

I wonder if it's actually possible to connect the contour without doing a straight line, which will make me lose a lot of information.

Approximating the "curveness" or "straightness" according to the neighbor?

[image]

Comment: What does your input image look like?  Perhaps a different approach from using canny edges would be better, such as thresholding and finding the contour.

Comment: the input image is the canny edge image. :) Cannot avoid that

Comment: What image did you start with before the canny and any other processing?

Comment: Try [cv2.minEnclosingCircle](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) and [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1)

Comment: @nathancy I tried cv2.minEnclosingCircle, but it's creating a bigger circle around my object. How could I use it to close my object ? Thank you.