# Find a height of object using OpenCV

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

I have an image. I have to find the height of a particular object in it.

If we directly take the pixel length it will not give the exact height.How to approach this problem?

Comment: Do you have any information about the object you are looking for?  Your calibration can map a point in the image to a ray in world coordinates but that alone will not tell you the height.  Without depth information about the object or several frames from different perspectives you can't resolve the height of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you calibrated your camera, you will have a transformation from image plane to world coordinates. Using this information you can predict the height of the object you are looking for, of course in this step you somehow need to identify the object that you are interested in.

Generally speaking, this question is too broad and covers many fundamental concepts of computer vision, so please consult your favorite textbook before attacking the problem.

Comment: I have already tried camera calibration , but its not giving acceptable results, have tried homographs too. No luck.

Comment: camera calibration is a common way to attack your problem, are you sure that you set up everything correctly while calibrating your camera?

Comment: As far as I know I have set up everything perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach: place the object on top of a **A4 paper sheet** and take a picture from above. Since you know the size of paper, you can calculate the size of the object based on that.

To detect a paper sheet, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863060/176769) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10533233/176769).