# opencv detect perfect square shape

Tags: python, opencv, contour

> i have binary edged image, after applying houghline i have detected
>   all lines in the image, after HoughLines i got following mask image:

[image: HoughLines]

> after this , i applied convexhull to detect perfect shapes , the
>   binary image i get after applying hull,

[image: convexhull]

after this am trying to apply contouring , and detect shapes using `approxPolyDP`, to find shapes with 4 sides, which will be square or rectangle, but as can be seen there is square approximately rectangular in shape, but as it's having 4 sides it's also detected as square, but i want to exclude these shapes , so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advanced square detection (with connected region)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997733/advanced-square-detection-with-connected-region)

Comment: before applying convexHull you should reduce the lines to their intersections