# split a table in an image into rows by whitespace using computer vision applications

Tags: python, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, ocr

I am trying to solve what I have realized is quite a hard problem to address due to my lack of expertise in the subject. Suppose I have an image of a table with 3 rows and 5 columns. Each row contains text (let's assume only english for now) or numbers (normal Indo-Arabic numerals). There is nothing but whitespace between the columns and between each row. Now assuming all rows and all columns are aligned, my task would be to get an algorithm to recognize and extract each row out from the document (don't know if I'm articulating this well enough).

Could someone suggest a good starting point (library , similar example , textbook chapter that deals with something like this) etc.. for me to get started.

My background is data science but I have just never been exposed to computer vision.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at open cv: http://opencv.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should start off with **OpenCV**, like Racialz suggested. This tool contains a **Hough lines/Hough transform** method which should be the primary and easiest way for  you to find and crop text from table sections. There are many different tasks for lines to find for which people use this algorythm (like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533233/opencv-c-obj-c-advanced-square-detection) or [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square)), but with your task it would be much easier, because lines should be much clearer and simplier, rather than in these examples. After you do your extraction, you then will need to scan your text, for this I would suggest you using **tesseract** ocr engine. This engine is for free, really easy to use, it provides pretty decent results and allows you to train it to scan specific types of letters.